# NodeJS Object # Has no method 'get'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a request to an endpoint which should return some user credentials to me, but am getting back the following error:

```
TypeError: Object # has no method 'get'\n at main:52:14\n at main:59:24
 at new SandBox (/home/server/node-host/sandbox/index.js:66:9)
 at builder.back (/home/server/node-host/test.js:48:17)
 at builder.count (/home/server/node-host/sandbox/build.js:139:7)
 at done (/home/server/node-host/sandbox/build.js:24:7)
 at builder.compiler (/home/server/node-host/sandbox/build.js:62:2)
 at new builder (/home/server/node-host/sandbox/build.js:13:10)
 at Object. (/home/server/node-host/sandbox/build.js:143:13)
 at Object.build (/home/server/node-host/sandbox/index.js:111:37)
```

Here's the code I tried to run (with the sensitive parts taken out and replaced with variables):

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: 'HOST',
  path: 'PATH',
  protocol: 'https'
};

var req = http.get(options, function(response) {
  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ${chunk}');
  });
});

req.write()
req.end() 
console.log('ended');
```

Comment: Your code must be shadowing `http` the http module with another object somewhere.

Comment: This is all I've got. I'm testing it on JSApp.US if that makes any difference, but I've got no other code in the entire sandbox, so I can't see how `http` would get shadowed?

Comment: Does it work with `http.request` and `method: 'GET'` in the `options` instead?

Comment: That gives the same error, but with "request" in place of "get" in the stack trace.

Comment: This is a jsapp.us restriction, not a node problem, really. There's other reports about this around.

Comment: Shoot... I was thinking that's the last thing it may be. Do you know of any other ways I can test my requests with the http module? I want to be able to test my requests and make sure I'm getting back what I expect to in the format I expect it it come back in.

Comment: There are many ways to make an http request: softwares (Fiddler for example), your browser, client side javascript (jQuery can help), local nodejs if you must or https://tonicdev.com/ if you really want to run nodejs code in your browser. You can even use [CURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).